# mongoDB admin permission in anydb

Tags: mongodb, permissions

i have this admin user

```
{ 
"_id" : "admin.admin", 
"user" : "admin", 
"db" : "admin", 
"credentials" : {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
        "iterationCount" : NumberInt(10000), 
        "salt" : "AAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==", 
        "storedKey" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", 
        "serverKey" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    }
}, 
"roles" : [
    {
        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase", 
        "db" : "admin"
    }, 
    {
        "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase", 
        "db" : "admin"
    }, 
    {
        "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase", 
        "db" : "admin"
    }
]
}
```

but if in console i try to change some role permission in other users i get a error **not authorized on admin to execute command**

But i have in my role mongo the correct authorization, why don't work?

i can run command without erros only in noauth mode (but i want use auth mode)